# Cannot get the score to update when using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a small quiz game on Tkinter and I cannot get the score to update correctly when a button is pressed. Instead of showing 500, it shows 0 and won't 'activate' the function which updates the score. How do I get the score to show correctly when the button is pressed?

```
score = 0
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainMenu)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Maths Picture/Button
        global photo
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "MathsPicture.png")
        photoimage = photo.subsample(3,3)
        tk.Label(self, text="MainMenu", font=('Verdana', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, image = photo, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageTwo), event()]).pack()
        
def event(event=None):
    global score
    score += 500
    print(score)
    

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    global score
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Label(self, text=score , font=("Verdana", 18, "bold")).pack(side="bottom")
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu)).pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page two", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = SampleApp()
    window.geometry("800x800")
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: tkinter window]

Comment: `text = Score` means that you are specifying *the function itself* as the text to be displayed, rather than the result of actually calling the function.  That would be `text = Score()`, although that wouldn't do anything useful either since the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: In addition to the above answer, if you wish to update the global variable `score` inside the function called `Score` you should use `global Score` at the start of the function.

Comment: Your current example code here seems to work okay once I added the imports at the top.  By clicking on the image, it goes to page 1 to display score, and when you press the goto page2 button from the main page, it adds to the score.  Is it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off function Score() does not return anything

simplest solution would be to make score a global variable and when event occurs do

```
score += 500
```

which is the same as `score = score + 500`
and as text just do `score` which is the variable and you should make it global

Edited code:

```
score = 0
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainMenu)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Maths Picture/Button
        global photo
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "MathsPicture.png")
        photoimage = photo.subsample(3,3)
        tk.Label(self, text="MainMenu", font=('Verdana', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, image = photo, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageTwo), Score()]).pack()
        
def event(event=None):
    global score
    score += 500
    # asign this function to a button or sth

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    global score
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Label(self, text=score , font=("Verdana", 18, "bold")).pack(side="bottom")
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Update score', command=event)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page two", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Update score', command=event)
```

Comment: I've updated the code but the score won't update still. The question has been updated to show new code and problem

Comment: you need to have a button or event bind that will execute event(). I did a little tweak to my code try it now. Also as I have noticed you can make just one class -> Window for example and then create 2 instances of that class to make 2 pages

Comment: Also as I have noticed you can make just one class -> Window for example and then create 2 instances of that class to make 2 pages. You can check [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM) for better understanding of classes